# Put array of elements under correct header with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have an array of vendors called:

```
$listOfVendors
```

I loop through this array with a foreach in my view.

```
<?php foreach($listOfVendors as $vendor):?>         

    <p class="vendor">
        <span class="vendor-title"><?php echo $vendor->name ?>(<?php echo $vendor->country ?>)</span>, 
        <?php echo $vendor->goods ?>, <a href="<?php echo $vendor->site_adres ?>" class="vendor-link"><?php echo $vendor->site_adres ?></a>
    </p>                                            

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Each vendor object has the following properties:

**vendors_Id**, **name**, **country**, **goods**, **site_address**, **activities_Id**. The last one, activities_Id, is a FK to the table activities which has, for the time being, two types of activities: Dealers and Artists.

Now I want to add a header once for every type of vendor. So want to get something like:

**Artist**

Vendor1(DE), Eigen posters e.a. merchandise, http://www.linktosite.com

**Dealer**

Vendor2(BE), Toys, DVD's, books, http://www.anotherlink.be

Vendor3(FR), Merchandise, http://www.anotherlink2link.be

How do I do this?
I just can't seem to get my head around this seemingly simple thing.

### Edit for Solution

#### Controller actvities -> function vendors

```
//Get the vendor information and add the needed headers
//Here I get all the vendors
if($listOfVendors = $this->atsusacon_model->get_records()) { 
    foreach($listOfVendors as $vendor) {
        $listOfVendorsByType[$vendor->activities_Id][] = $vendor;   
    }   
    $data['listOfVendorsByType'] = $listOfVendorsByType;    
    var_dump($listOfVendorsByType);
}
```

#### View actvities/vendors

```
<section class="vendors-overview twelvecol clearBoth">

    <?php foreach($listOfVendorsByType as $activity):?> 

        <?php if ($activity[0]->activities_Id == 1) :?> 
            <h3>Artists</h3>
         <?php else :?>
            <h3>Dealers</h3>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php foreach($activity as $vendor):?>      

            <p class="vendor">
                <span class="vendor-title"><?php echo $vendor->name ?>(<?php echo $vendor->country ?>)</span>, <?php echo $vendor->goods ?>, <a href="<?php echo $vendor->site_address ?>" class="vendor-link"><?php echo $vendor->site_address ?></a>
            </p>                                    

        <?php endforeach ?>         
    <?php endforeach ?> 

</section>
```

I could make it more dynamic but for now, this is exactly how it should be.

The var_dump of $listOfVendorsByType looks like this:

[image: Var_dump($listOfVendorsByType)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a nested array:

```
<?php 
 foreach($listOfVendors as $vendor) {
   $vendorsByType[$vendor['activities_id']][] = $vendor;
 }
?>
```

Now you have just have to loop over this nested array using two foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you have to get the data for the foreign key, than you have to loop twice:
Make sure you "link" vendor and activites correctly.

```
foreach (activities ...) {
  // looping 2 times
  foreach (vendor ...) {
    // looping x times (=amount of vendors)
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar to what blockhead posted but his answer provided a better "start" to the solution of my problem.

Comment: No problem. I can't see in his solution though where he tries to get the data for activities - seems like this part is still missing!?

Comment: In my original code I inserted the listOfVendors directly into my data array. In my view I then loop through the listOfVendors as you can see in my question but doing just that makes it impossible or at least very hard to create headers like I posted in my question. Blockhead then suggested to create a nested array in my controller. So I have an array in an array where my vendor objects are ordered according to their activities_Id.
I'll update my question with a screen of var_dump($listOfVendors) and how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this array

```
$header = array( "header1", "header2", "header3" );
```

//now $header[0] = "header1" $header[1] = "header2" so on

```
$i=0;
<?php foreach($listOfVendors as $vendor):?>         
<p class="header">
<?php echo $header[$i]; $i++; ?>
</p>
<p class="vendor">
    <span class="vendor-title"><?php echo $vendor->name ?>(<?php echo $vendor->country ?>)</span>, 
    <?php echo $vendor->goods ?>, <a href="<?php echo $vendor->site_adres ?>" class="vendor-link"><?php echo $vendor->site_adres ?></a>
</p>                                            

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Nice try but not quite what I was looking for.